# Animate UIBarButtonItem from right in NavigationItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to get my `UIBarButtonItem` to slide in from the right into the `leftBarButtonItem` position.

Either slides to the wrong place and then jumps when it's set as the `leftBarButtonItem` or isn't visible at all. This is what I'm attempting at the moment..

```
func createLeftBarButton() {
    // Get the nav bar we'll be working with
    var toolbar = self.navigationItem
    // Initialise our button
    cancelButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    cancelButton.setTitle("+", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cancelButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: "cancel:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cancelButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 34.0)

    // Create a placeholder to get the position and size of the leftBarButtonItem
    placeholderView = UIView(frame: cancelButton.bounds)
    placeholderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    toolbar.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: placeholderView)

    // Get the frame and position of the placeholderView
    var finalFrame: CGRect = self.view.convertRect(placeholderView.bounds, fromCoordinateSpace: placeholderView)

    // Set the frame for the button to the right of the final location.. this is probably wrong at the moment.
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(-1 * cancelButton.bounds.size.width, finalFrame.origin.y, cancelButton.bounds.size.width, cancelButton.bounds.size.height)

    // Add the button to the view
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(cancelButton)
    // Animate it to the final position
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.cancelButton.frame = finalFrame
        }, completion: { _ in
            // Finally set it to the leftBarButtonitem
            toolbar.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.cancelButton)
    })


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with the placeholder view / subviews is a bit overcomplicated. As is, your code doesn't show anything at all because your cancelButton doesn't have a frame, and then your placeholder view inherits that empty frame. But even with that you still have issues with the button sliding in below where it's supposed to be, and then snapping back.

Think this accomplishes what you're looking for:

```
    func createLeftBarButton() {
    // Get the nav bar we'll be working with
    var toolbar = self.navigationItem
    // Initialise our button
    cancelButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    cancelButton.setTitle("+", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cancelButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: "cancel:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cancelButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 34.0)
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
    // Create a placeholder to get the position and size of the leftBarButtonItem
    toolbar.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cancelButton)

    var delta = self.cancelButton.frame.size.width
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectOffset(cancelButton.frame, -delta, 0.0)

    // Animate it to the final position
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectOffset(self.cancelButton.frame, delta, 0.0)
        }, completion: { _ in
    })
}
```

Comment: The button now seems to appear in the right place but it doesn't animate

Comment: it's because the cancel button needs to be added to the subview.

Comment: Animates fine for me. When are you calling the function?

Comment: it worked fine after I added the line `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(cancelButton)`

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary; already added to the view after the cancel button is set as the left bar button item. When are you calling the function createLeftBarButton ?

Comment: Well I tested it on a clean project with a nav controller and root view and it worked fine; must be something different in your setup. Btw I just noticed your question says "slide in from the right". This actually does a slide in from the left. Same idea though.